# $|f(t) - f(s) |\leq \int_s^t g $ then $f(t) - f(s) = \int_s^t h.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, integration, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f : [0,1] \rightarrow [0, + \infty)$. If there exists $g \in L^1([0,1]) $ s.t. for every $t,s \in [0,1]$ holds
>   $$ |f(t) - f(s)| \leq \int_s^t g(u) \, du \quad (t>s),$$
>    then there exists $h \in L^1([0,1])$ s.t. for almost every $t,s \in [0,1]$ holds
>   $$f(t) - f(s) = \int_s^t h(u) \, du \quad (t>s).$$

Is this true? I suspect that there is a quite straightforward way to show this, but can't figure it out. I suppose that one could prove the statement using absoulte continuity and Lebesgue integral theorem, but I'm actually looking for a direct proof of the statement.

Comment: no, it is not true. $f(t)=\int_0^th(x)dx$ would imply that $f(t)$ has to be continuos a.e. Now, it is enough to choose $f$ to be bounded that "very discontinuous" to guarantee existence of $g.$

Comment: Yes you are right, I adjourned the statement

Comment: If $f$ is decreasing you could take $g \equiv 0$. But there exist non-AC decreasing functions. Should the first inequality have $|f(t) - f(s)|$ instead of $f(t) - f(s)$?

Comment: The most natural way to do this would be to just prove absolute continuity (which is clear from the condition you have given).  Otherwise, you need to prove that your candidate derivative is Lebesgue integrable, which essentially means reproving that absolute continuity is equivalent to the existence of an $L^1$ derivative